# como generar archivo de salida de los comandos solicitados

Tags: python, ssh, stdout

tengo la siguiente consulta, tengo este código que la idea es hacer lo siguiente:en el cual se suministra el nombre de usuario (user) y se tiene también el password que es pass para conectarse por ssh a diferentes routers. Adicional a ello, se tiene un archivo donde están las IP de los routers, se acceda a ellas y se guarda en un archivo aparte los siguientes comandos "sh inventory" y "show runn". Esa es la idea del programa, pero no genera el archivo al empezar a buscar el error si le quito  la parte del sdout, si se conecta a los equipos pero no genera ningún archivo. si dejo todo el código saca error al conectarse por ssh. Que podrá ser? gracias

```
import paramiko
import getpass

def ejecutar_comandos_ssh(ip, usuario, clave, comandos):
    # Crear una instancia de la clase SSHClient de Paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Configurar la política de aceptación automática de claves (esto es inseguro y solo se debe usar en entornos de prueba)
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Conectar al router
        ssh.connect(ip, username=usuario, password=clave, look_for_keys=False)

        # Ejecutar los comandos y obtener la salida
        salida = ""
        for comando in comandos:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando)
            salida += f"\n\n======= {comando} en {ip} =======\n\n"
            salida += stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        
        return salida

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al conectar por SSH a {ip}: {e}")
        return None

    finally:
        # Cerrar la conexión SSH
        ssh.close()

def leer_direcciones_ip(desde_archivo):
    try:
        with open(desde_archivo, 'r') as archivo:
            direcciones_ip = archivo.read().splitlines()
        return direcciones_ip
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"El archivo {desde_archivo} no se encontró.")
        return []

def guardar_resultado_en_archivo(ip, resultado):
    # Crear el nombre del archivo con la IP del router
    nombre_archivo = f"output_{ip}.txt"

    # Guardar el resultado en el archivo
    with open(nombre_archivo, 'w') as archivo:
        archivo.write(resultado)

    print(f"Resultado guardado en {nombre_archivo}")

# Configuración de la conexión SSH
usuario = "user"
clave = "pass"  

# Archivo con direcciones IP de routers
archivo_ips = "direcciones_ips.txt"

# Comandos a ejecutar en cada router
comandos_a_ejecutar = ["sh inventory", "show runn"]

# Leer direcciones IP desde el archivo
direcciones_ips = leer_direcciones_ip(archivo_ips)

# Ejecutar comandos y guardar la salida en un archivo por cada router
for ip in direcciones_ips:
    resultado = ejecutar_comandos_ssh(ip, usuario, clave, comandos_a_ejecutar)

    if resultado:
        guardar_resultado_en_archivo(ip, resultado)
```

Comment: comparte algo referente al error que muestra en pantalla

Answer (score 1):

-ejecuta este script | en el archivo: direcciones_ips.txt escribe la ----dirección ip del router para obtener la ip del router ejecuta en el cmd ipconfig
-este script no funcionara si el Servicio SSH no está Habilitado:

### Verifica en la configuración del router si el servicio SSH está habilitado. Debes habilitar el servicio SSH en el router para permitir conexiones SSH.

### script|

```
import paramiko


def ejecutar_comandos_ssh(ip, usuario, clave, comandos):
    # Crear una instancia de la clase SSHClient de Paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Configurar la política de aceptación automática de claves (esto es inseguro y solo se debe usar en entornos de prueba)
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Conectar al router
        ssh.connect(ip, username=usuario, password=clave, look_for_keys=False)

        # Ejecutar los comandos y obtener la salida
        salida = ""
        for comando in comandos:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando)
            salida += f"\n\n======= {comando} en {ip} =======\n\n"
            salida += stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        
        return salida

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al conectar por SSH a {ip}: {e}")
        return None

    finally:
        # Cerrar la conexión SSH
        ssh.close()

def leer_direcciones_ip(desde_archivo):
    try:
        with open(desde_archivo, 'r') as archivo:
            direcciones_ip = archivo.read().splitlines()
        return direcciones_ip
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"El archivo {desde_archivo} no se encontró.")
        return []

def guardar_resultado_en_archivo(ip, resultado):
    print(resultado)
    # Crear el nombre del archivo con la IP del router
    nombre_archivo = f"output_{ip.replace('.', '_')}.txt"  # Reemplazar puntos para evitar problemas en el nombre del archivo

    # Guardar el resultado en el archivo
    with open(nombre_archivo, 'w') as archivo:
        archivo.write(resultado)

    print(f"Resultado guardado en {nombre_archivo}")

# Configuración de la conexión SSH
usuario = "user"
clave = "pass"  

# Archivo con direcciones IP de routers
archivo_ips = "direcciones_ips.txt"

# Comandos a ejecutar en cada router
comandos_a_ejecutar = ["sh inventory", "show runn"]

# Leer direcciones IP desde el archivo
direcciones_ips = leer_direcciones_ip(archivo_ips)

# Ejecutar comandos y guardar la salida en un archivo por cada router
for ip in direcciones_ips:
    resultado = ejecutar_comandos_ssh(ip, usuario, clave, comandos_a_ejecutar)
    print(resultado)
    introducir el código aquí
    if resultado:
        guardar_resultado_en_archivo(ip, resultado)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, los equipos si tienen permitido conexión por ssh, realicé este otro código y lo ejecuta sin problema, el punto es que al querer generar un archivo con los comandos para cada equipo no me permite.

Comment: el otro código me funciona sin problemas si lo hago sin lista de equipos, asi: # Lista de direcciones IP de routers Cisco
ips_routers = ["10.111.134.105", "10.111.134.157", "10.36.43.107"]Comando ejecutado en 10.111.134.105 y salida guardada en output_show_version.txt
Comando ejecutado en 10.111.134.105 y salida guardada en output_show_inventory.txt
Comando ejecutado en 10.111.134.157 y salida guardada en output_show_version.txt
Comando ejecutado en 10.111.134.157 y salida guardada en output_show_inventory.txt
Comando ejecutado en 10.36.43.107 y salida guardada en output_show_version.tx

Comment: otro error cuando intento con el primer código es: Error al conectar por SSH a 10.36.43.107: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

Comment: hola buen dia, ejecute el script con las modificaciones que pusiste, esta fue la salida, pero los equipos si tienen acceso por ssh, con otro script si me funciona: la salida es esta:C:\python>py new.py
Error al conectar por SSH a 10.111.134.157:
None
Error al conectar por SSH a 10.111.134.105:
None
Error al conectar por SSH a 10.36.43.107:
None